# How to send a Content-Type form-data request using rest assured?

Tags: java, api, automation, backend, rest-assured

I need to invoke a form-data typed API using Rest Assured. Here is my code.

```
private Map<String, String> getFormParamsMap() {
  Map<String, String> formParams = new HashMap<>();
    formParams.put("creatorId", "Instructor1");
    formParams.put("creatorPlatform", "Web");
    formParams.put("creatoredSource", "File");
    formParams.put("creatoredType", "Auto");
    formParams.put("deckId", "5a605b472e02d86561172dad");
    formParams.put("userId", "kind");
    return formParams;
}

public void invoke() {
          response = given()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/form-data")
                    .header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME, accessToken) //Some API contains access token to run with the API
                    .headers(headers)
                    .formParams(getFormParamsMap()) // requestParamsMap here.
                    .when()
                    .post(invokingEndpoint);
}
```

When I execute this, I am getting the below error.

```
Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to encode creatorPlatform=Web&creatoredType=Auto&deckId=5a605b472e02d86561172dad&creatorId=Instructor1&creatoredSource=File&userId=kind as a byte stream.

Please use EncoderConfig (EncoderConfig#encodeContentTypeAs) to specify how to serialize data for this content-type.
For example: "given().config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("application/form-data", ContentType.TEXT))). .."
Stack Trace:
io.restassured.internal.http.EncoderRegistry.encodeStream(EncoderRegistry.java:130)
```

When I use `.config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("application/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)))` in the `invoke()` method, it gives the result as below.

```
{
"status": 400,
    "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1' not supported",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"
}
```

My request is not `x-www-form-urlencoded` type, it is `form-data` type. I can execute it using postman.

Appreciate your support on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @ankitMISHRA Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this issue by using `encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)`

Ex:-

```
public void invoke() {
     response = given()
                .config(
                        RestAssured.config()
                                .encoderConfig(
                                        encoderConfig()
                                                .encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)))
                .headers(headers)
                .formParams(formParams)
                .when()
                .post(oAuthBaseURI).then().extract().response();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the consumer as well.

See [here](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.6/io/restassured/http/ContentType.html#fromContentType-java.lang.String-) for the encoders available for Rest Assured. 
This might be causing the problem -

```
encodeContentTypeAs("application/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)
```

You can also try this -

```
.encoderConfig(encoderConfig().appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false).encodeContentTypeAs("application/form-data", ContentType.TEXT));
```

Comment: Still it is getting the below error response
{
"status": 400,
    "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"
}

Comment: Try Vytas suggestion or can you try changing the ContentType to JSON if not set at the consumer?  If no error, the problem is with the encoderConfig

Comment: You mean changing to this encodeContentTypeAs("application/json")

Comment: Yes. I don't think header encoding might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `headers(headers)` method replaces all headers, and then RestAssured uses `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type as default.

Try adding "Content-Type" header after the call to `headers(headers)`.

Comment: Now I am getting this error
{   "status": 400,
    "message": "Content type 'application/form-data' not supported",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException"
}

Comment: The server is rejecting your request because it appears not to be configured to handle `application/form-data` content type. Does it have `consumes = MediaType.FORM_DATA` or similar?