# always getting Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing but works on postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to get my access token with a post request.
I have tried the request on postman and it works perfectly.
but when trying from my app I get the error

> {error: "invalid_request", error_description: "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

This is the java code that i have tried:

```
    RestAssured.baseURI 
    ="http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/acme/protocol/openid- 
    connect/token";
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("grant_type", "password");
    requestParams.put("username", "amineamine"); // Cast
    requestParams.put("password", "amineamine");
    requestParams.put("client_id", "app-backend-springboot");
    requestParams.put("client_secret",  "9a1707db-431d-437c-bb70- 
    0e5f5d61dcb0");

    request.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
    request.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
    charset=UTF-8");

    Response response = request.post();
    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println(response.print());
    System.out.println("The status code recieved: " + statusCode);
    System.out.println("Response body: " + 
    response.body().asString());
```

These are the imports:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

> in postman
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwU7z.png)

Comment: Can you show us the Postman request that is working?

Comment: @Steve i have update the post and i add the postman screenshot in the header a set Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: my brother, have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see one significant problem with your code that I would think could very well explain your problem.  You are sending JSON, and yet you are sending a Content-Type header that suggests you are sending form data.

Since your Postman example is sending form data, I assume that's what you want to do.  Leave the Content-Type header the way it is, but change your POST body to be form data.  The way you have it, the two don't match up.  The proper structure of form data is not JSON.

Here is an existing post on how to send form data using RestAssured:

[How to send a Content-Type form-data request using rest assured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843435/how-to-send-a-content-type-form-data-request-using-rest-assured)

To summarize, you want to put your parameters in a Map and then pass that map to the `formParams()` method in the request builder chain.

Comment: i have change the Content-Type header value to application/json and i get the same error also oauth2 accept string query for the body so i should send it with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: See the URL I added to my answer

Comment: i have tried an other approche with rest template .

Comment: I don't know what you're saying.  The answer, via the supplied link, shows you the right way to send your data as form data, which it seems is what you want to do.  If you're trying to do this, and it isn't working, put that code in your question.  The code you show in your question won't work, and I've told you why in my answer. - The explanation tells you why your Postman request works and your Java doesn't.  They are sending the data in different formats.  The Postman request is sending form encoded data, and your Java code is sending JSON.